# extraneous or missing lines when deriving polygons from sf (multi)linestrings

Tags: r, r-sf

I have an sf `MULTILINESTRING` called `cells_mls` and a `LINESTRING` `circle_ls`:

[image]

I'd like to divide the circle into a set of polygons based on `cells_mls`. Using `st_union()` then `st_polygonize()` almost gets me there, but with one extraneous line segment:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

st_union(cells_mls, circle_ls) %>% 
  st_polygonize() %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(linewidth = 1) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 18)
```

[image]

If I instead start with the circle as a polygon and use `st_intersection()`, I'm missing a few segments:

```
circle_poly <- st_polygon(list(circle_ls))

st_intersection(cells_mls, circle_poly) %>%
  st_union(circle_ls) %>%
  st_polygonize() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(linewidth = 1) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 18)
```

[image]

How do I resolve these issues, or should I be using a completely different approach?

Data:

```
cells_mls <- structure(list(structure(c(1.62040594860963, 0.328589161396787, 
-0.346689411460563, -0.928479707596478, 2.20348085798978, 0.676651008833335, 
0.484900807161357, 2.39841068466972), dim = c(4L, 2L)), structure(c(-2.39870911617957, 
-0.400611620057257, 0.00630746222993039, -0.50236177279798, -0.415147118124876, 
-2.37331382718479), dim = 3:2), structure(c(0.214192388889373, 
-0.187574375144797, -0.496893207101343, -0.346689411460563, 0.328589161396787, 
0.214192388889373, -0.206728224065068, -0.191497351759491, 0.306210481328579, 
0.484900807161357, 0.676651008833335, -0.206728224065068), dim = c(6L, 
2L)), structure(c(1.71479068804203, 0.214192388889373, 0.328589161396787, 
1.62040594860963, -1.52892516271685, -0.206728224065068, 0.676651008833335, 
2.20348085798978), dim = c(4L, 2L)), structure(c(-2.4965069512518, 
-0.496893207101343, -0.187574375144797, -0.400611620057257, -2.39870911617957, 
0.266905593533409, 0.306210481328579, -0.191497351759491, -0.415147118124876, 
-0.50236177279798), dim = c(5L, 2L)), structure(c(0.00630746222993039, 
-0.400611620057257, -0.187574375144797, 0.214192388889373, 1.71479068804203, 
-2.37331382718479, -0.415147118124876, -0.191497351759491, -0.206728224065068, 
-1.52892516271685), dim = c(5L, 2L)), structure(c(-0.928479707596478, 
-0.346689411460563, -0.496893207101343, -2.4965069512518, 2.39841068466972, 
0.484900807161357, 0.306210481328579, 0.266905593533409), dim = c(4L, 
2L))), class = c("XY", "MULTILINESTRING", "sfg"))

circle_ls <- structure(c(1, 0.9998468455, 0.9993874289, 0.998621891, 0.9975504662, 
0.9961734827, 0.9944913623, 0.9925046202, 0.9902138651, 0.9876197985, 
0.9847232151, 0.9815250021, 0.9780261392, 0.9742276981, 0.9701308423, 
0.9657368267, 0.9610469971, 0.9560627903, 0.9507857328, 0.9452174411, 
0.9393596208, 0.9332140662, 0.9267826597, 0.9200673713, 0.9130702581, 
0.9057934631, 0.8982392156, 0.8904098292, 0.8823077023, 0.8739353167, 
0.8652952367, 0.8563901091, 0.8472226615, 0.8377957019, 0.828112118, 
0.8181748759, 0.8079870194, 0.7975516693, 0.7868720219, 0.7759513485, 
0.7647929943, 0.7534003771, 0.7417769865, 0.7299263831, 0.7178521965, 
0.7055581254, 0.6930479355, 0.6803254588, 0.6673945923, 0.6542592968, 
0.6409235958, 0.6273915741, 0.6136673767, 0.5997552075, 0.5856593279, 
0.5713840556, 0.5569337632, 0.5423128769, 0.5275258754, 0.5125772879, 
0.4974716934, 0.4822137189, 0.4668080379, 0.4512593694, 0.4355724762, 
0.4197521631, 0.4038032762, 0.3877307008, 0.3715393599, 0.3552342132, 
0.338820255, 0.3223025131, 0.3056860471, 0.2889759467, 0.2721773304, 
0.2552953437, 0.2383351577, 0.2213019676, 0.2042009906, 0.1870374651, 
0.1698166483, 0.1525438151, 0.1352242564, 0.1178632773, 0.1004661956, 
0.0830383401, 0.0655850494, 0.0481116693, 0.0306235521, 0.0131260547, 
-0.0043754633, -0.021875641, -0.0393691181, -0.0568505361, -0.0743145402, 
-0.0917557811, -0.1091689164, -0.1265486123, -0.1438895452, -0.1611864034, 
-0.1784338888, -0.1956267183, -0.2127596255, -0.2298273626, -0.2468247015, 
-0.2637464357, -0.2805873821, -0.297342382, -0.3140063032, -0.3305740415, 
-0.347040522, -0.3634007009, -0.3796495669, -0.3957821427, -0.411793487, 
-0.4276786952, -0.4434329016, -0.4590512805, -0.4745290478, -0.4898614626, 
-0.5050438285, -0.5200714949, -0.5349398587, -0.5496443656, -0.5641805115, 
-0.5785438438, -0.592729963, -0.6067345236, -0.620553236, -0.6341818673, 
-0.6476162431, -0.6608522481, -0.6738858282, -0.686712991, -0.6993298074, 
-0.7117324128, -0.7239170081, -0.7358798612, -0.7476173076, -0.7591257521, 
-0.7704016696, -0.7814416061, -0.79224218, -0.8028000831, -0.8131120812, 
-0.8231750158, -0.8329858044, -0.842541442, -0.8518390016, -0.8608756353, 
-0.869648575, -0.8781551335, -0.8863927052, -0.8943587668, -0.9020508783, 
-0.9094666835, -0.9166039109, -0.9234603742, -0.9300339733, -0.9363226947, 
-0.9423246119, -0.9480378867, -0.953460769, -0.9585915976, -0.963428801, 
-0.9679708975, -0.9722164957, -0.9761642954, -0.9798130871, -0.9831617533, 
-0.9862092681, -0.9889546982, -0.9913972026, -0.9935360331, -0.9953705346, 
-0.9969001451, -0.9981243961, -0.9990429127, -0.9996554134, -0.9999617106, 
-0.9999617106, -0.9996554134, -0.9990429127, -0.9981243961, -0.9969001451, 
-0.9953705346, -0.9935360331, -0.9913972026, -0.9889546982, -0.9862092681, 
-0.9831617533, -0.9798130871, -0.9761642954, -0.9722164957, -0.9679708975, 
-0.963428801, -0.9585915976, -0.953460769, -0.9480378867, -0.9423246119, 
-0.9363226947, -0.9300339733, -0.9234603742, -0.9166039109, -0.9094666835, 
-0.9020508783, -0.8943587668, -0.8863927052, -0.8781551335, -0.869648575, 
-0.8608756353, -0.8518390016, -0.842541442, -0.8329858044, -0.8231750158, 
-0.8131120812, -0.8028000831, -0.79224218, -0.7814416061, -0.7704016696, 
-0.7591257521, -0.7476173076, -0.7358798612, -0.7239170081, -0.7117324128, 
-0.6993298074, -0.686712991, -0.6738858282, -0.6608522481, -0.6476162431, 
-0.6341818673, -0.620553236, -0.6067345236, -0.592729963, -0.5785438438, 
-0.5641805115, -0.5496443656, -0.5349398587, -0.5200714949, -0.5050438285, 
-0.4898614626, -0.4745290478, -0.4590512805, -0.4434329016, -0.4276786952, 
-0.411793487, -0.3957821427, -0.3796495669, -0.3634007009, -0.347040522, 
-0.3305740415, -0.3140063032, -0.297342382, -0.2805873821, -0.2637464357, 
-0.2468247015, -0.2298273626, -0.2127596255, -0.1956267183, -0.1784338888, 
-0.1611864034, -0.1438895452, -0.1265486123, -0.1091689164, -0.0917557811, 
-0.0743145402, -0.0568505361, -0.0393691181, -0.021875641, -0.0043754633, 
0.0131260547, 0.0306235521, 0.0481116693, 0.0655850494, 0.0830383401, 
0.1004661956, 0.1178632773, 0.1352242564, 0.1525438151, 0.1698166483, 
0.1870374651, 0.2042009906, 0.2213019676, 0.2383351577, 0.2552953437, 
0.2721773304, 0.2889759467, 0.3056860471, 0.3223025131, 0.338820255, 
0.3552342132, 0.3715393599, 0.3877307008, 0.4038032762, 0.4197521631, 
0.4355724762, 0.4512593694, 0.4668080379, 0.4822137189, 0.4974716934, 
0.5125772879, 0.5275258754, 0.5423128769, 0.5569337632, 0.5713840556, 
0.5856593279, 0.5997552075, 0.6136673767, 0.6273915741, 0.6409235958, 
0.6542592968, 0.6673945923, 0.6803254588, 0.6930479355, 0.7055581254, 
0.7178521965, 0.7299263831, 0.7417769865, 0.7534003771, 0.7647929943, 
0.7759513485, 0.7868720219, 0.7975516693, 0.8079870194, 0.8181748759, 
0.828112118, 0.8377957019, 0.8472226615, 0.8563901091, 0.8652952367, 
0.8739353167, 0.8823077023, 0.8904098292, 0.8982392156, 0.9057934631, 
0.9130702581, 0.9200673713, 0.9267826597, 0.9332140662, 0.9393596208, 
0.9452174411, 0.9507857328, 0.9560627903, 0.9610469971, 0.9657368267, 
0.9701308423, 0.9742276981, 0.9780261392, 0.9815250021, 0.9847232151, 
0.9876197985, 0.9902138651, 0.9925046202, 0.9944913623, 0.9961734827, 
0.9975504662, 0.998621891, 0.9993874289, 0.9998468455, 1, 0, 
0.0175010154, 0.0349966701, 0.052481605, 0.0699504644, 0.0873978972, 
0.1048185593, 0.1222071146, 0.1395582367, 0.1568666108, 0.1741269353, 
0.1913339232, 0.2084823037, 0.2255668243, 0.2425822517, 0.259523374, 
0.2763850019, 0.2931619706, 0.3098491412, 0.3264414022, 0.3429336712, 
0.3593208966, 0.3755980587, 0.3917601718, 0.4078022853, 0.4237194852, 
0.439506896, 0.4551596819, 0.4706730483, 0.4860422433, 0.5012625592, 
0.5163293339, 0.5312379523, 0.5459838476, 0.5605625033, 0.5749694535, 
0.5892002855, 0.6032506401, 0.6171162136, 0.6307927589, 0.6442760867, 
0.6575620669, 0.6706466299, 0.6835257679, 0.6961955357, 0.7086520526, 
0.720891503, 0.7329101378, 0.7447042757, 0.7562703039, 0.7676046798, 
0.7787039314, 0.789564659, 0.8001835358, 0.8105573093, 0.8206828017, 
0.8305569116, 0.8401766145, 0.8495389637, 0.8586410914, 0.8674802097, 
0.876053611, 0.8843586692, 0.8923928403, 0.9001536635, 0.9076387616, 
0.9148458417, 0.9217726963, 0.9284172037, 0.9347773285, 0.9408511226, 
0.9466367255, 0.9521323651, 0.9573363579, 0.9622471101, 0.9668631172, 
0.9711829656, 0.9752053318, 0.9789289839, 0.9823527812, 0.985475675, 
0.9882967087, 0.9908150183, 0.9930298323, 0.9949404724, 0.9965463532, 
0.9978469829, 0.9988419631, 0.999530989, 0.9999138496, 0.9999904276, 
0.9997606995, 0.9992247358, 0.9983827004, 0.9972348515, 0.9957815406, 
0.9940232129, 0.9919604068, 0.9895937544, 0.9869239805, 0.983951903, 
0.9806784321, 0.9771045705, 0.9732314131, 0.9690601461, 0.9645920473, 
0.9598284852, 0.9547709191, 0.949420898, 0.9437800607, 0.9378501352, 
0.9316329377, 0.9251303726, 0.9183444318, 0.9112771939, 0.9039308235, 
0.896307571, 0.8884097714, 0.8802398439, 0.871800291, 0.8630936979, 
0.8541227314, 0.8448901394, 0.8353987499, 0.8256514703, 0.8156512863, 
0.8054012609, 0.7949045338, 0.7841643203, 0.7731839103, 0.7619666671, 
0.7505160266, 0.7388354963, 0.726928654, 0.714799147, 0.7024506905, 
0.6898870671, 0.6771121251, 0.6641297775, 0.650944001, 0.6375588345, 
0.623978378, 0.6102067913, 0.5962482928, 0.582107158, 0.5677877186, 
0.5532943607, 0.5386315238, 0.5238036992, 0.5088154288, 0.4936713036, 
0.4783759625, 0.4629340906, 0.4473504177, 0.4316297174, 0.415776805, 
0.3997965365, 0.3836938067, 0.367473548, 0.3511407289, 0.3347003521, 
0.3181574537, 0.3015171008, 0.2847843905, 0.2679644481, 0.2510624258, 
0.2340835009, 0.2170328741, 0.1999157681, 0.1827374262, 0.1655031101, 
0.1482180989, 0.1308876872, 0.1135171835, 0.0961119084, 0.0786771933, 
0.0612183787, 0.0437408124, 0.0262498479, 0.0087508428, -0.0087508428, 
-0.0262498479, -0.0437408124, -0.0612183787, -0.0786771933, -0.0961119084, 
-0.1135171835, -0.1308876872, -0.1482180989, -0.1655031101, -0.1827374262, 
-0.1999157681, -0.2170328741, -0.2340835009, -0.2510624258, -0.2679644481, 
-0.2847843905, -0.3015171008, -0.3181574537, -0.3347003521, -0.3511407289, 
-0.367473548, -0.3836938067, -0.3997965365, -0.415776805, -0.4316297174, 
-0.4473504177, -0.4629340906, -0.4783759625, -0.4936713036, -0.5088154288, 
-0.5238036992, -0.5386315238, -0.5532943607, -0.5677877186, -0.582107158, 
-0.5962482928, -0.6102067913, -0.623978378, -0.6375588345, -0.650944001, 
-0.6641297775, -0.6771121251, -0.6898870671, -0.7024506905, -0.714799147, 
-0.726928654, -0.7388354963, -0.7505160266, -0.7619666671, -0.7731839103, 
-0.7841643203, -0.7949045338, -0.8054012609, -0.8156512863, -0.8256514703, 
-0.8353987499, -0.8448901394, -0.8541227314, -0.8630936979, -0.871800291, 
-0.8802398439, -0.8884097714, -0.896307571, -0.9039308235, -0.9112771939, 
-0.9183444318, -0.9251303726, -0.9316329377, -0.9378501352, -0.9437800607, 
-0.949420898, -0.9547709191, -0.9598284852, -0.9645920473, -0.9690601461, 
-0.9732314131, -0.9771045705, -0.9806784321, -0.983951903, -0.9869239805, 
-0.9895937544, -0.9919604068, -0.9940232129, -0.9957815406, -0.9972348515, 
-0.9983827004, -0.9992247358, -0.9997606995, -0.9999904276, -0.9999138496, 
-0.999530989, -0.9988419631, -0.9978469829, -0.9965463532, -0.9949404724, 
-0.9930298323, -0.9908150183, -0.9882967087, -0.985475675, -0.9823527812, 
-0.9789289839, -0.9752053318, -0.9711829656, -0.9668631172, -0.9622471101, 
-0.9573363579, -0.9521323651, -0.9466367255, -0.9408511226, -0.9347773285, 
-0.9284172037, -0.9217726963, -0.9148458417, -0.9076387616, -0.9001536635, 
-0.8923928403, -0.8843586692, -0.876053611, -0.8674802097, -0.8586410914, 
-0.8495389637, -0.8401766145, -0.8305569116, -0.8206828017, -0.8105573093, 
-0.8001835358, -0.789564659, -0.7787039314, -0.7676046798, -0.7562703039, 
-0.7447042757, -0.7329101378, -0.720891503, -0.7086520526, -0.6961955357, 
-0.6835257679, -0.6706466299, -0.6575620669, -0.6442760867, -0.6307927589, 
-0.6171162136, -0.6032506401, -0.5892002855, -0.5749694535, -0.5605625033, 
-0.5459838476, -0.5312379523, -0.5163293339, -0.5012625592, -0.4860422433, 
-0.4706730483, -0.4551596819, -0.439506896, -0.4237194852, -0.4078022853, 
-0.3917601718, -0.3755980587, -0.3593208966, -0.3429336712, -0.3264414022, 
-0.3098491412, -0.2931619706, -0.2763850019, -0.259523374, -0.2425822517, 
-0.2255668243, -0.2084823037, -0.1913339232, -0.1741269353, -0.1568666108, 
-0.1395582367, -0.1222071146, -0.1048185593, -0.0873978972, -0.0699504644, 
-0.052481605, -0.0349966701, -0.0175010154, 0), dim = c(360L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following workflow:

- casting your circle_ls line object to a polygon (so that it can be split)
- use a `lwgeom::st_split()` call to blast the circle as polygon to pieces, using cell_mls as a "blade"
- the result will be a geometry collection; extract only polygons from it

That should be it...

```r
circle <- st_cast(circle_ls, "POLYGON")

inside <- lwgeom::st_split(circle, cells_mls) %>% 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON")

plot(inside)
```

[image]